# How do I make an image clickable in a navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I've currently created a navigation bar for my website for university assignment. I've implemented an image on their which is the universities logo which I'd like to link to the university homepage. However, when I try to use the anchor tag '' to make the image clickable to link to the homepage, it messes up for the style of my navigation bar and would like to know if there's a workaround. I know the issue is that the image will take on the styles of the anchor tags I have declared for the navigation bar. I'll include images of before and after creating the link and show the HTML and CSS of that section.

[image: This is the image link before I change the link]

This is the navbar before making the image clickable.

This is the HTML for it:

```
<div class="top_nav"> 
    <img class="logo" src="images/NTU_badge.png" alt="NTU Badge">
    <a class="active" href="#Home"> Home </a>
    <a href="#Hackathon">Hackathon</a>
    <a href="#Choose_a_Challenge">Choose a Challenge</a>
    <a href="#Digital_Horizons"> Digital Horizons </a>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for it:

```
.top_nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #ed0162;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.top_nav a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: monospace;

}

.top_nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ed0162;
    color: white;
}


.logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

This is the HTML and webpage after I try to make the image clickable:

[image: ]Broken Nav Bar]

There is now big spacing inbetween and the hover style now affects the image when I don't want it too.

The HTML code after:

```
<header>

    <div class="top_nav"> 
        <a href="https://www.ntu.ac.uk/">
        <img class="logo" src="images/NTU_badge.png" alt="NTU Badge">
        </a>
        <a class="active" href="#Home"> Home </a>
        <a href="#Hackathon">Hackathon</a>
        <a href="#Choose_a_Challenge">Choose a Challenge</a>
        <a href="#Digital_Horizons"> Digital Horizons </a>


    </div>

</header>
```

I've tried removing the 'logo' class from the image style but it doesn't really change it that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that it's generally pretty poor practice to use element names (such as `a` and `div`) in CSS selectors at all, for this exact reason.

Consider adding something like `class="navigation"` to each link in your navbar, and then change the `.top_nav a` selector to `.top_nav .navigation`. Then you could add a similar class to the logo `<a>`.

Not only does this make the CSS more specific, but much more readable when someone else (or you in six months' time) has a look at this without any other context of the rest of the page.

Comment: Would this fix my problem?

Comment: It would. Making the image an `<a>` is applying to it the same CSS that is applied to the navigation links. By making the CSS and HTML style-specific, you will be able to style each //type// of element individually instead of trying to get a single style to cover all bases. If you're doing this for an assignment, personally, I think it's better to learn long-term solutions that will help you in the future than have a single specific solution for this one instance. I'd recommend against `:first-of-type`-style solutions, because someone reading the CSS alone has no idea what that refers to.

Comment: Ok, I've done this and it worked, however, when I change the active css to .navigation.active or navigation.active and use class="navigation, active" the active css no longer applies

Comment: `class="navigation active"` - CSS classes in HTML are space-delimited, not comma-delimited. Also, class selectors in CSS always start with `.`, so `.navigation.active` was correct. `navigation.active` would be trying to select `<navigation class="active"></navigation>`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out snazzybouche, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this but flexbox makes it really easy.  also will simplify your css.  Just wrap the image in a anchor tag to make it clickable.

```css
.top_nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    font-size:2vw;    
    width: 100%;
}

.top_nav a {
    width:10%;    
    color: white;    
    text-decoration: none;   
    font-family: monospace;

}

.top_nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ed0162;
    color: white;
}

img{
   width:100%;
   }
   
   #short{
      width:2.5%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="top_nav"> 
    <a id='short' href='https:\\www.google.com'><img class="fa facebook" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/facebook-square-brands-blue.png" scale="0"></a>
    <a class="active" href="#Home"> Home </a>
    <a href="#Hackathon">Hackathon</a>
    <a href="#Choose_a_Challenge">Choose a Challenge</a>
    <a href="#Digital_Horizons"> Digital Horizons </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work, I'm a bit confused at your answer.

Comment: how does it not work? It seems to work in the snippet.  show us what you tried as a snippet so we can more easily spot the problem you are having. state exactly what's confusing you.

Comment: All I did was copy parts of your css and then add it to the anchor tag, for example if you go to www.trapstar.com if you click on the trapstar icon in the top corner it takes you to the homepage, but when I click mine it shows the hover effect and messes the spacing up.

Comment: First, www.trapstar.com doesn't seem to exist.  Be that as it may, You need to show us your code or at least provide a link to your website.  The problem is not the provided solution but something interfering with it from your code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use the [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo css selector. Something like that would be the correct way to handle it:

```
.top_nav a:first-of-type {padding: 0;}
```

EDIT

I'm sorry, on the original answer i miss the part to advice you wrapping your image with `a` element. So change this:

```
<img class="logo" src="images/NTU_badge.png" alt="NTU Badge">
```

To:

```
<a href="URL" target="_blank">  <img class="logo" src="images/NTU_badge.png" alt="NTU Badge" /></a>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @Henry Update the answer (: